# Use Web Worker on onChange event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, web-worker

I want to ask if it is a good approach to use WebWorker in onChange event. Like new instance of webworker will be created on every change in Input Element.

I have to run some calculation and that calculation will take time so that's why I want to send the VALUE that i will get from input element to web worker so that all the calculation will be done in background.

here is the example Code

```
const handleOnChange = async (e: any) => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    setInputValue(value);

    const worker: Worker = new SearchWorker();
    worker.postMessage({ value });

    worker.addEventListener(
      "message",
      function (e) {
        setOutCome((state: any) => [...state, e.data]);
      },
      false
    )
}
```

Comment: No, it's a very bad idea. A Web Worker is an heavy object, it has its own event loop, its own js environment, its own globalscope etc. Starting one is i  itself a huge operation (which even includes network negotiation etc.). To add to that, if you start more Workers than there are free CPU threads on the conputer, you'll make all the processes that will share this thread stop working in parallel, but instead in task switching, which means they'll all be slower. So, start only at max `navigator.hardwareConcurrency - 1` Workers, and make them do multiple tasks, they can queue it don't worry.

Comment: how can I create just one instance of it and send data to worker in OnChange of input? I'm using react typescript.

Comment: You store the worker in a variable accessible to your script, outside of the change event handler, and you keep posting messages to the same worker instance.

Comment: I created a singleton class where i create the instance for my worker and it worked for me. Thanks